# phpMyDirectory alternative

Tags: web-development

I have been using [phpMyDirectory](https://www.phpmydirectory.com/) for my local directory for over 6 years and, as the software is no longer supported, I am looking to switch my website to an actively developed non-WordPress directory software with similar features and the ability to import my listings and user accounts. Any recommendations? Thanks.

Comment: [Are you sure it's  no longer supported?](https://www.phpmydirectory.com/)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, my issues are not resolved since 2017. I received one reply from support after 6 months of waiting with no solution. It became open source recently and looks like, being an official commercial license owner, I have to pay a donation fee to receive support now, but I do not trust the software anymore as there are so many unresolved issues on GitHub.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, demos doesn't run...

Answer (score 0):

After about 6 months of trial and error, I have completed my research and can confidently recommend anyone who finds themselves in a situation like me to trust the [phpListings](https://www.phplistings.com) script without hesitation. It's been months since their team imported my content from PMD and everything is working perfectly fine. In fact, I got an absolutely identical business directory website with the functions I am used to, but phpListings is a much more modern solution and their code works fine with PHP 7.4.

The main criteria for me when looking for an alternative were:

1 Only pure PHP code. Not WordPress.

2 Custom form fields of different types, as close as possible to my current directory of companies that was working on phpMyDirectory.

3 Ability to bind categories and form fields to packages, as it was in phpMyDirectory, so that only certain paid packages get access to premium categories and fields. And, lo and behold, in phpListings I found an absolutely identical feature with the ability to synchronize existing listings when updating their package.

4 Ability to transfer my existing records from PMD with maximum accuracy. phpListings were the only ones who agreed to make the transfer, although, as far as I understand, it took them a huge amount of time and resources. By the way, they did it for free.

And also in phpListings there are widgets for constructing pages that I could only dream of in PMD and a responsible support service. Dear phpMyDirectory friends, switch to phpListings, I assure you, you can't go wrong.